# C++ Difference between method returning member by ref and get-set method

Tags: c++, get, set

As far as I can understand as new comer to C++, both intends to expose a private member to public. We can say like this:

```
// Make everything outside can see value of name
object.get_name(); // get method
object.name();     // return member by ref to get

// Make everything outside can set value of name
object.set_name("Name"); // set method
object.name() = "Name";  // return member by ref to set
```

- What's difference between those two way of accessing private member?
- Why bother not to just create a public member if all I need is just to
  get or set without doing anything else inside those functions?

Comment: this is no big difference. But if you use getter and setter, you can validate value and do some work if possible. if you use public member, when you need to add some code when get or set, you will have to modify all refs.

Comment: The getter/setter approach allows you to change the class' internal representation and maintain invariants.

Answer (score 1):

With set_name, you can perform validation on the input, and throw exceptions as necessary. You can also update any other class members at the same time.

If you return a reference, you lose control of what can be set since the member can be modified through the reference. In fact, you may as well have the member variable public, as you point out.

Answer (score 1):

you can have more control when you use a set function, rather than returning a reference to an internal class member (validation of input, exception throwing etc.).

```
class Foo{
    std::string name;
public:
    const std::string& get_name() const;
    void set_name(const std::string&); // perform input validation inside set_name
};
```

If you expose the class member via a public function returning a reference to it you have removed the purpose of it being private in the first place.

Moreover, if the object is shared between multiple threads it may be necessary to synchronize access to the object's state. For that you would typically lock a mutex inside the object's functions.

```
class Foo{
    mutable std::mutex mtx; // mutable so that it can be modified in const-qualified functions
    std::string name;
public:
    std::string get_name() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{mtx};
        return name;
    }

    void set_name(const std::string& str)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{mtx};
        name = str;
    }
};
```

By having the synchronization taking place inside get/set-functions the class itself handles the synchronization, without you having to worry about data races.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is the following:

1. If your class is just a collection of independent variables (e.g. 3
   dimensions of a vector or name, birth date and adress of a person)
   then just use public members.
2. If your class has to maintain some
   invariants (e.g. the allowed days in a date depends on the year and
   month) use private members and public setter/getter methods that
   enforce those invariants.
3. Sometimes, you also want to allow only read or only write access or you have "simulated" properties, which don't map directly to a specific member variable, but are calculated from them. In those cases you obviously also need separate setter and getter methods (or only one of them).
4. Finally, the only common case - I know of - in which you want to return
   a non-const reference to a private variable is in containers, where
   you acces an element by its index or key.